# check email regex does not contain sub string

Tags: .net, regex

I need to check that the period is not followed directly by the at symbol.

I have tried:
^(?!.@).*$

But this does not seem to work.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I honestly don't see the need for regular expressions in this situation, when you can simply search for the literal string ".@" and crash if its matched.

---

Putting that aside, one regex solution is with a negative lookbehind, which it seems like you have attempted:

```
(?<!\.)@
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/S7rG6exqeFF3Mgvz)

I'm not clear why you have the start and end-of-line boundaries, if all your trying to detect is a bad sub-string, but you can certainly add them in:

```
^.*(?<!\.)@.*$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/Jc43pxsAEREM6XeH)